# Something in the bootstrap css prevents bing map 6.3 to show

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bing-maps

I am trying to use the Bing maps v.6.3 Ajax control with a page that uses bootstrap ( the latest version 2.1.0)
For some reason when I include the bootstrap min css, the map refuses to render,
if I remove the reference to the bootstrap css it renders fine

The jsfiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/WnPHb/

With bootstrap css
[image: With bootsrap css]

Without bootsrap css
[image: Without bootsrap css]

Has anyone run into this before ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the `max-width: 100%` style setting for `img` elements in **bootstrap.css**.  I would recommend restoring to the default (`none`) for all images in the map container:

```css
.MSVE_MapContainer img {
  max-width: none;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/8BPHc/)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth

this is what I had to comment out in the

```
img{max-width:100%;vertical-align:middle;border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
```

I hope that this helps someone some day.